# Password check from the database, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, sqlite, uitextfield

```
-(IBAction)EnterButtonPressed:(id)sender
{ 
const char *sql = "SELECT AccessCode FROM UserAccess";
double result = ([Password.text doubleValue]);
if(sql == result )
{
    NSLog(@"Correct");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Wrong");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing you're doing wrong is not sending that SQL query to the database. You probably ought to add in some kind of `WHERE` clause too. And... well, there's quite a lot wrong with that code to be honest.

Comment: On a plus side, I now know the password is “SELECT AccessCode FROM UserAccess” (literally!)

Comment: thanks donal .. noob here ... Sorry AccessCode was the column name lets say the password is 12345 .. thats what I want to extract from AccessCode FROM UserAccess ( the table )

Comment: Your first step is to get that DB query happening. To do that, you're going to have to use the SQLite C API. Google for an example; the top hit for "iphone sdk sqlite example" is highly informative. Then you'll need to consider what data you are storing, what you are looking up, etc.